# Is it possible to change a Content Element Name when using Content Elements?

Tags: control-panel, custom-fields, content-elements

Is it possible to change a Content Element Name when using Content Elements? I can only see how to delete and re-add the Content Element from scratch, but you then lose all your data. I'm using Content Elements 1.6.10 and EE 2.8.1, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not currently possible (as of Content Elements 1.6.10) to rename a Content Element. The only workaround is to delete an element and create a new one. I've made a feature request for this to be added though.